# string a to i problem on leetcode my solution fails incase of 2 consecutive signs

Tags: java, string, loops

problem link: https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/
i have implemented my solution but it fails for testcase like "-+42"since 2 consecutive signs appear in string. what changes do i need to do in my code, and where am i wrong? help would be appreciated

my code:

```
 class Solution {
    public int myAtoi(String s) {
      s=s.trim();
        char sign='+';
        
      if (s.length()==0) return 0;
        String digit="";
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            //checking for sign
             if(s.charAt(i)=='-'||s.charAt(i)=='+')
                sign=s.charAt(i);
            //checking for all non digit characters
            else if((s.charAt(i)>='a'&& s.charAt(i)<='z')||(s.charAt(i)>='A' && s.charAt(i)<='Z')||(s.charAt(i)==' ')||(s.charAt(i)=='.')||(s.charAt(i)=='-')||(s.charAt(i)=='+'))
           
            break;
            
             else{
                 digit=digit+s.charAt(i);
             }   
            
        }
        if(digit=="") return 0;
        
            
        //System.out.print(sign);
        try{
        int n=(Integer.parseInt(digit));
            //int a=Integer.parseInt(digit);
            System.out.print(sign);
            if(sign=='-')
            return (-n);
            return n;
        }
        //check for out of range for integer
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            if(sign=='-')
               
            {
                //
                int n=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
             return n;}
            
            else
            {
                int n=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                return n;
            }
        }
                
          
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be helpfull to know what error it throws and at what line it happens.

Comment: Maybe you should check for `-` and `+` outside the loop, not inside.

Comment: You could start by actually **following the instructions** given in the challenge, e.g. only skip leading spaces (`trim()` removes more than just spaces), only look for and process a single leading sign character (not do it repeatedly in a loop), and only collect digits (the code e.g. collects `$` characters too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Er, just.. do what the exercise says? Not sure what you want to hear from SO here. I guess: "Can you regurgitate the question to me". Can do!

Your algorithm isn't doing anything like what the exercise spells out you need to do. You are triggering on a sign character appearing anywhere, and your code scans for letters, all things which the exercise doesn't mention. At all. The exercise mentions the concept of a 'not a digit' and **the first** character (after getting rid of spaces, which you already did with a `trim()` invocation).

So, do what the exercise says:

Instead of `if (s.charAt(i) == '-'` your code needs to involve `s.charAt(0)` - there are only 3 options:

- The trimmed string starts with a `+`. Set the sign to +, and start looking at digits from position 1.
- The trimmed string starts with a `-`. Set the sign to -, and start looking at digits from position 1.
- Neither. Set the sign to + and start looking at digits from position 0.

Your `s.charAt(i) >= 'a'` is also wrong. You're not looking for a letter. You're looking for anything that isn't a digit. `+` isn't a letter. Nevertheless, in input `-5+10`, you're supposed to return `-5`. In `-+10` you're supposed to return 0. (Because that's like `-hello` - the negative value of no digits, which is minus zero, which is just zero).

I think the intent of the exercise is not to use `Integer.parseInt` whatsoever.

Try this algorithm:

- if your character is `>= '0'` and `<= '9'`, you can subtract `'0'` to get the actual digit in integer form: `char c = '5'; int y = c - '0'; System.out.println(y);` would print 5.
- multiply your existing input by 10, then add the digit you have. In other words, for text input `"29"`, first you read a 2, you multiply the number you're working on (`0`, at first) to 10 (still `0`), then you add `2`, giving you 2. Then you get another digit, so you multiply what you ahve so far by 10 (giving you 20), and add the digit value, getting you the integer 29. No need for `parseInt`.
- You now you need to clamp when your working total flips signs on you. So, if all of a sudden your input is negative (as you won't yourself make it negative until the very end), you know you have to clamp and return `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, depending on the sign value.

Comment: thank you! I am still a beginner and trying to improve, so this definitely helps,I finally understood my mistakes